# Error when run migrations on Heroku, PostgreSQL with Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I deploy Rails 5 with PostgreSQL to free app in Heroku. This is my configuration from `database.yml`:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  username: root
  password:
  database: example
```

When I run `heroku run rake db:migrate`, I see this error:

> rake aborted!
>   PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
>       Is the server running locally and accepting
>       connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

If I add this line to `database.yml`:

```
host: localhost
```

and run migration again, I see this error:

> rake aborted!
>   PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
>       Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
>       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

How to fix it ?

Comment: Can you print the output of `heroku config --app your_app_name` command?

Comment: LANG:                     en_US.UTF-8
RACK_ENV:                 production
RAILS_ENV:                production
RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT:      enabled
RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES: enabled
SECRET_KEY_BASE:          yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy KEY HERE

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It seems like database is not provided for your app, you need to add one:

```
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql
```

You can verify the database was added to your application by running:

```
heroku config --app your_app_name
```

Answer (score 1):

After delete old DB, you should execute this

```
heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_NEW_DATABASE
```

You can check your DB nickname by

```
heroku pg:info
```

Comment: Why should OP *delete* a database when the problem is to connect?

Answer (score 0):

Follow some steps in serial order,

1. `$ heroku login`
2. In Gemfile, add the pg gem to your Rails project. Change:

   `gem sqlite` 
   to

   `gem 'sqlite3', group: :development` 
   `gem 'pg', '0.18.1', group: :production`
3. In Gemfile, add the rails_12factor gem::

   `gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production`
4. `$ bundle install`
5. Ensure config/database.yml is using the postgresql adapter. Change:

   `production:`
   `<<: *default`
   `database: db/production.sqlite3`
   to

   `production:`
   `<<: *default`
   `adapter: postgresql`
   `database: db/production.sqlite3`
6. `$ git add .` 
   `$ git commit -m "Heroku config"`
7. `$ heroku create`
8. `$ git push heroku master`
9. `$ heroku run rake db:migrate`

   I hope it worked.

SO FOLLOW STEP 5 correctly.

Comment: `rails_12factor` is no needed for Rails 5. Check documentation: https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor